# Children's sci-fi book with protagonists lost on distant planet

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

Been trying to identify a book I read in the late early 90s for quite a few years now, 
It was a children's/ young adult sci-fi story.

**Plots Summary/Details:**
 A boy (teenager possibly) had accidentally stowed away on a spacecraft [named Orion, this may have been part of the title and was certainly the cover illustration] which had a experimental faster then light drive, called shifts or something similar, and had landed up on a distant planet; the ship returned automatically without him.

The spaceship creator and some other kids (his nephews?) then had to return there to retrieve him. the ship creator watched a video of a drone/robot vehicle from the ship leaving and being destroyed by alien, but keeps it  from every one else for some reason

There were a race of 'dolphin like' aliens, who were slaves to a race 'horse like aliens' on said planet which the protagonists freed while trying to save the missing boy, before returning home, after having had their ship modified by the aliens.

(I may have misremembered parts of the plot, as it was a long time ago.)

**Timeframe of Publication** I read it in the early or mid 90s, so no later than then, I suspect it may have been earlier so more likely 1980s or even late 70s

Comment: I’ve been looking for this book for years for my kids as I loved it as a child. I borrowed it from village library in 1985 or ‘86, so definitely 80s. I believe it was called The White Planet and had a sequel, although never been able to locate it under that name. I recall the cover was green with a snowy scene and text in the classic 1980s future font. Would love to find a copy!

Comment: If you can't find a matching book titled _The White Planet_, that would suggest that isn't the correct title of the book you're looking for, in which case this doesn't constitute a valid answer. Please note that the 'Your Answer' field should only be used to answer the question, not merely to comment on it. You need to earn a minimum of 50 reputation in order to leave actual comments in this thread. What you can do right now though is post your own story-ID question by clicking on the ['Ask Question'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button at the top of the page.

Comment: Incidentally, it's perfectly fine to post your own question, even if you think you're looking for the same (as-yet-unidentified) book as a previous user. You also shouldn't rule out the possibility that you may be thinking of a similar-yet-different book, but it doesn't matter either way. If you do post your own question, try to tell us everything you remember about the book you read. The more detailed your description, the easier it'll be to identify it.

Comment: *The White Planet* by Carol Main? https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/main_carol - "*[a] lightly sketched Space Opera [with] adventures on various planets"

Comment: http://wilmu2.trglib.gov.my/neuseal/Cover/Show?author=Main%2C+Carol&callnumber=FIK+MAI&size=large&title=The+white+planet+Carol+Main..&recordid=0000060074&source=Solr&isbn=0340279680 - Cover